# How to control a jsonp callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I am sending a jsonp request and I also manipulate locally the response from the server.

I am trying to trigger the callback function that is called `foo()` when the response return and can't figure out how to do it.

this is how I send the request:

```
function jsonp(url, success, failed) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", url + questionMark + "callback="+"foo" + "&cachebuster="+new Date().getTime());
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

this is how the json file looks like:

```
bar({key:value, key: value ...})
```

I have these 2 functions:

```
function foo(data) {

}

function bar(data) {

}
```

**The problem is that bar is being executed and I want foo to be executed.** How do I manipulate through the script only (and how should I write the json file itself) so I determine in the javascript what is the callback function (and not in the json file itself). I want to be independent from the json and decide which callback to tirgger in the scripts.

Comment: You can call foo function from bar function or return JSONP foo({});bar({});

Comment: If you have control on server that generates the response, change generated response JS. If no, change your JavaScript function bar(data){ foo(data); }

Comment: thanks! but is there a way not to be dependent at all on the file? so the file will look like "({key:value...})" and I can create the callback myself?

Comment: @Alon That depends on the server, whether it supports it or not. From your example it seems that it is not supporting it.